# Access SSM Parameter Store from Lambda Custom Runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have a lambda function with the purpose of check database connectivity from a specific VPC and subnet. I created a lambda function with custom runtime, put it in a VPC and subnet, and upload a binary file to that and just call this binary file to test the connectivity.

But I need some get the database URL and credentials from the SSM parameter store, anyone knows how to do that using Lambda Custom Runtime?

I see that using python, node ... is pretty simple: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/sharing-secrets-with-aws-lambda-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store

But using a custom runtime, only with shell, is that possible? If not, any ideas or suggestion to do that as simple as possible?

Comment: Does you custom runtime have access to the AWS CLI?

Comment: @stdunbar no, but if it is possible, and not a bad thing to do... we can consider adding that

Comment: With the AWS CLI it's very easy to access SSM.  You could use it to set environment or shell variables for credentials.